# how to identify particular string between two strings

Tags: java, regex

First I have two strings: registration id and username. These two strings are concatenated.

why concatenate two string because some time user name is same but registration id is different so

I have this code:

```
public ArrayList getStudentUser(int check,int userid,int mgmtid)
{
    ArrayList companyList = new ArrayList();
    Session session = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    try {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    if(check==1){
        String query = "select a.firstname,a.lastName,b.RegistarionId from t_vs_users a inner join t_vs_userdetails b on b.UserId=a.User_ID  where a. RoleId=5 and  SourceId=? and a.User_ID not in (?)";
        pst = session.connection().prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, mgmtid);
        pst.setInt(2, userid);
        rst = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rst.next()) {
            companyList.add(rst.getString("firstname")+""+(rst.getString("lastName"))+","+rst.getString("RegistarionId"));
        }
    } else {
        String query = "select a.firstname,a.lastName,b.RegistarionId from t_vs_users a inner join t_vs_userdetails b on b.UserId=a.User_ID  where a. RoleId=5 and  SourceId=? and a.User_ID not in (?)";
        pst = session.connection().prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, mgmtid);
        pst.setInt(2, userid);
        rst = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rst.next()) {
            companyList.add(rst.getString("RegistarionId")+","+(rst.getString("firstname"))+""+rst.getString("lastName"));
        }   
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return companyList;
}

public boolean checkIfNumber(String in) {
      try {
          Integer.parseInt(in);
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
          return false;
      }
      return true; 
}
```

I get in concatenate  string getStudentUser but i want only registration id how to split

Comment: could you please add an example with expected result and what you get?

Answer (score 2):

You already have the values as separate entities from the query.  You have to ask this question because you insisted on taking those values, concatenating them into a `String`, and returning them as a `List`.

```
companyList.add(rst.getString("firstname")+""+(rst.getString("lastName"))+","+rst.getString("RegistarionId"));
```

I think a better solution is to create an object of some kind, put the values as separate data members, and return a `List` of those instances instead of a `String`.

You're using Hibernate.  It's an ORM solution - Object-Relational Mapping.  Where are your objects?  I'd either ditch Hibernate or start writing objects.  You're not benefitting much in the code you've posted.

A `String` is not a good abstraction for anything.  It's little more than a primitive.  You'll write better code if you start thinking in terms of objects instead of primitives.

Here's a start on that model object:

```
package model;

public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // Add the rest
}
```

And the DAO:

```
package persistence;

public interface StudentDao {
    List<Student> find();
    Student find(Long id);
    List<Student> find(String lastName);
}
```

But, if you must, use the `split()` function to divide that comma-delimited String:

```
String [] tokens = result.split(",");
```

You'll have to figure out where the id is.

If you forget a comma, like you did after the first query, this won't work.  I'll assume it's a typo.

I'd recommend `StringBuilder` there, too.